# Find Index of DataRowView in DataView

Tags: c#, dataview, datarowview

Is there a way to get the index of a selected `DataRowView` in a `DataRow`?

I current have the following code

```
private long GetSelectedIndex(DataView dataView, string searchString)
{
    long selectedIndex = 0;

    foreach(DataRowView dataRow in dataView)
    {
        if(dataRow.Row.ItemArray.Contains(searchString)
        {
            //Do Something.... I've tried everything to get the index out of the dataRow
        }
    }

    return selectedIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe try

```
int index = dataView.Table.Rows.IndexOf(dataRow.Row)
```

Comment: I shall give this a whirl tomorrow

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Like it was just pointed out, this will just be the index of the table row, not the view row. The views row index changes based on the sorting method and probably the filter as well.

Comment: This won't work unless your DataView has the same rows and sort order as the parent DataTable!